# Delete pandas rows if column values are close to each other within a certain range

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I would like to remove all pandas rows where values in two columns are close to each other within a certain pre-defined range.

**For example:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6], \
'b':[20.02,19.96,19.98,20.10,26.75,56.12],\
'c':[10.12,10.10,123.54,124.12,245.12,895.21]})

a      b         c
1    20.02   10.12
2    19.96   10.10
3    19.98   123.54
4    20.10   124.12
5    26.75   245.12
6    56.12   895.21
```

Filter rows based on column b and c: if the current values of `b` and `c` are close to (within 1% of) the previous accepted row's values:

```
(0.99*previous_b < b < 1.01*previous_b) && (0.99*previous_c < c < 1.01*previous_c)
```

then they are excluded.

**Result**

```
a      b         c
1    20.02   10.12
3    19.98   123.54
5    26.75   245.12
6    56.12   895.21
```

I can use numpy.isclose for one number:

```
df['b'].apply(np.isclose, b=20.02, atol=0.01 * 20.02)
```

How can I generalize this so that I apply this iteratively running through all pandas columns and apply this condition on two different columns?

**Side note:**
I have two million rows in my pandas dataframe. Therefore, I would like to know the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: Next element in column b and c should be within 99% percent of the previous value in the same column. i.e (19.96 should be within 99% percent of 20.02 &&  9.89 should be 99 percent of 10.12). After that,  repeat this with 3rd row and 1st row. (because 2nd row was deleted)

Comment: I am sorry that column_b and column_c variables is confusing. I mean that the next value in the same column should be 99% percent close to the previous value in the same column.

Comment: Both column b and c should be within 99% percent of its previous value which is why row 4 is not included.

Comment: Yes, which is why row 4 is deleted exactly like row 2. I am trying to filter out rows where values are close to each other.

Comment: Damn, that's extremely stupid of me. It was my mistake. 9.89 was just a made up number it should be something like 10.10. I want to filter values where **both** column b and c are very close to its previous values.

Answer (score 2):

Given the rows being compared may change depending on the result of each comparison, I'm not sure you can achieve this without using some logic equivalent to a for loop:

```
#Taking initial comparison values from first row
b,c = df.iloc[0][['b','c']]
#Including first row in result
filters = [True]

#Skipping first row in comparisons
for index, row in df.iloc[1:].iterrows():
    if 0.99*b <= row['b'] <= 1.01*b and 0.99*c <= row['c'] <= 1.01*c:
        filters.append(False)
    else:
        filters.append(True)
        # Updating values to compare based on latest accepted row
        b = row['b']
        c = row['c']

df2 = df.loc[filters]
```

```
print(df2)

   a      b       c
0  1  20.02   10.12
2  3  19.98  123.54
4  5  26.75  245.12
5  6  56.12  895.21
```

---

Checking the edge case where row(n+1) is close to row(n) (and excluded), but row(n+2) is close to row(n+1) but is not close to row(n) (and thus should be included):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], \
                   'b':[20,20,20],\
                   'c':[100,100.9,101.1]})
```

```
   a   b      c
0  1  20  100.0
2  3  20  101.1
```

Comment: This is almost what I want. Instead of only comparing to the last accepted row like you showed, I would like it filter by comparing to **all** accepted rows so far. For example: `df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5], \
                   'b':[20,20,20,20,20],\
                   'c':[100,100.9,101.1,101.8,100.0]})` 
output should be:   
    `a     b    c  
    `1     20   100.0
    `3     20   101.1`

row5 should be excluded because it is similar to the previously accepted row1.

Comment: In case the output format was not clear. For the previous example, output should only contain row1 and row3. (2, 4 and 5 must be neglected.)

Answer (score 0):

Largely based on ukemi's earlier answer. In this example each column value is compared to all previously accepted rows instead of only the last accepted row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],'b':[20.02,19.96,19.98,20.10,26.75,56.12, 20.04,56.24, 56.15],\
               'c':[10.12,10.10,123.54,124.12,245.12,6.00,10.11,6.50,128.67]})


    a     b       c
0   1   20.02   10.12
1   2   19.96   10.10
2   3   19.98   123.54
3   4   20.10   124.12
4   5   26.75   245.12
5   6   56.12   6.00
6   7   20.04   10.11
7   8   56.24   6.50
8   9   56.15   128.67

b = []
c = []

#Taking initial comparison values from first row
b.append(df.iloc[0]['b'])
c.append(df.iloc[0]['c'])

#Including first row in result
filters = [True]

#Skipping first row in comparisons
for index, row in df.iloc[1:].iterrows():
    tag = 0
    for i in range(len(b)):
        #Thresholds have been changed to 5% and 10% respectively in this case.
        if 0.95*b[i] <= row['b'] <= 1.05*b[i] and 0.90*c[i] <= row['c'] <= 1.10*c[i]:
            filters.append(False)
            tag = 1
            break

    if tag == 0:
        filters.append(True)
        # Updating values to compare based on latest accepted row
        b.append(row['b'])
        c.append(row['c'])


df2 = df.loc[filters]

print(df2)

    a    b       c
0   1   20.02   10.12
2   3   19.98   123.54
4   5   26.75   245.12
5   6   56.12   6.00
8   9   56.15   128.67
```

Please let me know if there is a faster way to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I use `itertools.pairwise` which is available in python>=3.10.

1. sort the rows;
2. compare by pairwise in reversed order;
3. drop the higher one if within the criterion.

Assume that the column name is `key`, drop criterion is `EPSILON`.

```py
from itertools import pairwise
from tqdm import tqdm

df = ...
key = "key"
EPSILON = 1e-4

df = df.sort_values(by=[key])
for (i, iser), (j, jser) in tqdm(df[::-1].iterrows(), total=len(df) - 1):
    if iser[key] - jser[key] < EPSILON:
        df.drop(index=i, inplace=True)

print(df)
```